# Weird behaviour of tyrus Websocket API

Tags: java, json, tyrus

I am developing a websocket server and client which will handle multiple messages.

I am using JSON with decoders and encoders.

As we can have only one @OnMessage method per endpoint, I created one Marker interface called message. Now my @OnMessage method as parameters like `void @OnMessage(Message message, Session session)` in both Client and Server.

I am sending `Register_Send` object from @OnConnect of Client using `Session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject`. Server reads this message successfully and sends `Register_Received` object to client using  `Session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject`.
Both  `Register_Send` and  `Register_Received` implements Message interface. Both objects are encoded and decoded as JSON objects.

But at client side  `void @OnMessage(Message message, Session session)` method receives Register_Received object as Register_Send. Due to which, exception is thrown.

I am unable to resolve this issue,whether its fault in my code or in Tyrus 1.7 API.

Please suggest me solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you please share your code, which demonstrates your issue? (github ideally).

Comment: Dear @PavelBucek, you can find git repositories here:
https://github.com/ashishnijai/JSONMessages
https://github.com/ashishnijai/WebSocketClient
https://github.com/ashishnijai/WebSocketServer

Please go through code.
Used Eclipse IDE with JDK 7 and Tyrus 1.7 API.
Waiting for your response.

Comment: The issue is that your decoders are both returning "true" in willDecode method implementation. So they are always used in the declaration order, which favours "Register_Send_Decoder.class" on client side. You will need to implement willDecode better or remote unwanted decoders from @ClientEndpoint annotation.

Comment: Any reason of this favoring of "Register_Send_Decoder.class"?

Comment: BTW issue is solved. Will update detailed answer here.

I am working on console based ClientEndpoint.
Now I am sending two different types of messages to server. 
First message is sent by OnOpen method while second one is sent by using session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject() which is inside main() method of client.
Message is sent and responded by server. But OnMessage method in client is no reading response to second message. 
Did a lot of research, but unable to get solution. 

Suggest me some solution.

Comment: 1) The problem with your original code was that your decoders do not have willDecode methods implemented. Then they are picked in the declaration order and you have "Register_Send_Decoder.class" first in @ClientEndpoint declaration.

Comment: 2) Implement @OnError on both sides (@ServerEndpoint and @ClientEndpoint) and see whether they are called or not. My guess would be that you have still some encoder/decoder mismatch present in your code.